# Android: ImageView with svg looks blurry

Tags: android, svg, imageview, android-imageview, android-vectordrawable

I'm many svg exported from Adobe illustrator, it only have a size of 9.36*10.8.
When I use the xml vector of this svg (converted by Android Studio) as the src of ImageView with a size of 19.5dp * 22.5dp, the imageview looks blurr.
Shouldn't have svg have the ability to scale without any blurr?
I can't change the viewportWidth or viewportHeight.

P.S: I have enabled hardwareAcclerate, does that have issue with vector drawable too?

Sample SVG (I used this in BottomNavigationView item, it looks very blurry):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="6.4771dp"
    android:height="7.92dp"
    android:viewportWidth="6.4771"
    android:viewportHeight="7.92">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#cacaca"
      android:pathData="M3.2386,4.3201c1.0975,0 1.9791,-0.9702 1.9791,-2.16S4.3361,0 3.2386,0c-1.0975,0 -1.9791,0.9702 -1.9791,2.16s0.8816,2.16 1.9791,2.16ZM6.2722,5.625c-0.2732,-0.4733 -0.778,-0.765 -1.3244,-0.765L1.5293,4.86c-0.8446,0 -1.5293,0.685 -1.5293,1.53 0.001,0.8446 0.6851,1.5291 1.5293,1.53h3.4185c0.5464,0 1.0512,-0.2916 1.3244,-0.765s0.2732,-1.0566 0,-1.53Z" />
</vector>
```

I'm running Android 13 with AndroidX, Target Version 32 without any support library. Gradle 7.5.1

Comment: Please post the svg source code so we can try it out.

Comment: Can you post the "ImageView" XML?